# 401 Error when user has CRUD permissions for role in 2sxc Content app

Tags: 2sxc

I've set up a Content Manager role and assigned the role CRUD permissions in the 2sxc content module. Logging in as a user in the Content Manager role I see the edit icon, clicking on it I am able to edit the content (all as expected), however when I click on Save, I get a alert that pops up saying that Authorization has been denied for the request, despite having CRUD permissions...

[image: Popup Message[![]]

Any thoughts on what I can change to have this message not popup and have the permissions actually work as expected?
(Can't get Draft CRUD only to work either... but that's a different issue)

I am using the 2sxc Content version 10.25.2

Comment: So the fact that the edit opens means that read seems to work. Could you give the user a higher level to test if that works?

Comment: Also - please check the insights https://r.2sxc.org/insights to see what happens internally while saving.